# not able to find fips.ora file

Tags: oracle, fips

I am configuring Oracle Database in fips compliant mode, but not able to find fips.ora, can someone please tell me do i need to create a new file or there is any default location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on 11g, the fips.ora file is either located in the `$ORACLE_HOME/ldap/admin` directory, or is pointed to by the `FIPS_HOME` environment variable.

If it doesn't exist create it and add
`SSLFIPS_140=TRUE`

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28530/asoappe.htm